# Append HTML to a form field using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Lets say I have a form field and I want to `append` a `span` tag to it. Is it possible to do this with jQuery?

I tried this code:

```
$("input").append("<span>My HTML to append</span>");
```

Or would I have to use something else to append HTML.

So it would be something like this:

```
<input><span>My HTML to append</span></input>
```

But that wouldn't work.

Something like when you add tags to the question on StackOverflow each tag is a block.

Edit: How did StackOverflow do it when adding tags to the question.

Comment: you didn't append span to input tag.it won't apply

Comment: You can't append HTML to a form element. If you mean that you want to set it's value, use `val()`

Comment: I think you are looking for [after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) like `$("input").after("<span>My HTML to append</span>");`

Comment: @ArunPJohny: I bet you that's it, nice one.

Comment: Post the html that you expect to end up with

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I hope so... but not enough info to post it as an answer

Comment: @ArunPJohny No I want to append child nodes to the input element.

Comment: @user3588664 no that is simply not possible as others have already pointed out

Comment: @ArunPJohny How did StackOverflow do it.

Comment: @user3588664: They don't.

Comment: @user3588664 the tags are not shown in a input element, it is shown in a div element with a input element next to it

Comment: @user3588664: It is not part of the input field. It is "next" to it and then styled appropriatly

Comment: @user3588664 use your browser's developer tools to inspect the tags editor of so and you can see how is the markup structured

Comment: it will be much more easier for you use an existing library like [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#tags)

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks if you posted an answer I would've select it because only your comment works.

Comment: @user3588664 which comment... one recommending `after()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`input` elements cannot have any child elements, so you can't use `append` on them.

You can set their value by using jQuery's `val` method.

They won't *render* HTML in any case, if you set the value to `<span>My HTML to append</span>`, that's exactly what you'll see in the input.

---

Re your edit:

> So it would be something like this:
>
> `<input><span>My HTML to append</span></input>`

That's invalid HTML. Again [`input` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-input-element) cannot have content, they're ["void" elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#void-elements). This is why you can't use `append` on them.

---

Re your comment below:

> How did StackOverflow do it when adding tags to the question.

They don't. Instead, there's an input and when you complete a tag in the input, they remove it and put it in a span in front of the input, so you end up with:

```
<span>
    <span class="post-tag">tag</span>
    <span class="post-tag">another-tag</span>
</span>
<input type="text">
```

In any modern browser, right-click the tags input field and choose "Inspect element" to see this live.

Here's an **very** quick-and-dirty example of doing this (but there are lots of plugins out there for doing it — [tagit](http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/), [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) [which one of my clients uses and loves], ...): [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/xahuhufu/1)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Tags-Like Input</title>
  <style>
    .input-wrapper {
      border: 1px solid #aaa;
    }
    .post-tag {
      border: 1px solid #00a;
      margin-right: 2px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <input type="text" id="theInput">
  </div>
  <script>
    (function() {
      $("#theInput").on("keypress", function(e) {
        if (e.which === 32) {
          e.preventDefault();
          addTag($.trim(this.value));
          this.value = "";
        }
      });
      function addTag(tag) {
        $('<span class="post-tag"></span>')
          .text(tag)
          .insertBefore("#theInput");
      }
    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How did StackOverflow do it when adding tags to the question.

Comment: @user3588664: I've added a *very* quick-and-dirty example of doing this.

Answer (score 3):

An input element cannot have any child nodes, so no, you can't.

You could set the value (using the `.val()` method) to a string of HTML if you like.

You could concatenate that string with the existing value.

```
var $in = $("input");
$in.val(
    $in.val() + "<span>My HTML to append</span>"
);
```

Answer (score 2):

As other's have pointed out `input` element cannot have a child element.

So in a tagging system the common approach is to use a input element to select a tag once you do that add it to a container element which is placed next to the input element and style it such a way that they look like a single control.

In a very crude way you can use [.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/)/[.before()](http://api.jquery.com/before/) to do it like

```
$("input").after("<span>My HTML to append</span>");
```

But there are already many plugins available to do it, so I would recommend using one of them like [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#tags)